# How to say " I had a stupid question " more professionally or politely?

Tags: phrases

I want to ask questions that may be obvious or common knowledge to the person I'm asking. My natural instinct is to say " I had a stupid question ", should I say something that is more professional and polite?

Comment: “I have an obvious question” is probably more commonly used. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/example/english/obvious-question

Comment: It doesn't feel like it's an obvious question for them since they have answered it probably multilpe times before. Its just a very simple question that may come from my own ignorance

Comment: The best advice is in a comment on the duplicate. If your question isn't worth asking, don't ask it; but if it is, you don't need to apologize.

Comment: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/ or https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ would be good places for information on how to ask stupid questions.